# What is the meaning of bf() in brms package when we do cumulative regression analysis?

Tags: r, regression, hierarchical-bayesian, brms

I was trying to run a Bayesian multilevel cumulative model on ordinal data and was reading the documentation of `brms` online. My model looks something like

```
model <- brm(bf(y ~ Condition + (Condition|item) + (Condition|subject)),
                    data = df, 
                    family = cumulative(link="probit", threshold="flexible"),
                    chains=4,cores=4,iter=2000, prior = prior)
```

I saw that some documentations do not have the `bf()` function when specifying the formula but some do. Could someone explain to me what is `bf()` doing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `bf()` function is just to specify a formula, and using it for simple models inside the `brm()` function is not something you need to do. You could remove it in your example.

However, you can use the `bf()` function to save a formula as an object to pass to the `brm()` function, like this:

```
model_formula <- bf(y ~ Condition + (Condition|item) + (Condition|subject))

model <- brm(model_formula,
             data = df, 
             family = cumulative(link="probit", threshold="flexible"),
             chains=4,cores=4,iter=2000, prior = prior)
```

For more advanced formulas, you may need to use the `bf()` function to separate different parts of your model. For example, a linear model like this would not run if you didn't wrap the formula in `bf()`:

```
model <- brm(bf(y ~ x + (1+x|random_effect), sigma ~ x), ...)
```

Here are some links to pages describing more complex models that all use the `bf()` function to specify the formulas:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_distreg.html

https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/mixture.html